# fontawesome-webfont.ttf:1 not found in cakephp 2.10.12

Tags: cakephp, font-awesome

I load the font-awesome.css (4.7.0) in the head tag of layout.ctp cakephp as shown below

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery-3.4.0.js');?>
<?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery-ui.min.js');?>
<?php echo $this->Html->script('popper.min.js');?>
<?php echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap.js');?>
<?php echo $this->Html->script('moment.js');?>
<?php echo $this->Html->css('jquery-ui.css');?>
<?php echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap.css');?>
<?php echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css');?>
<?php echo $this->Html->css('all.min.css');?> 
<?php echo $this->Html->css('jquery-ui.theme.css');?> 
<?php echo $this->Html->css('font-awesome.css');?>
```

and then in my view, I just use the class called `fa fa-fw fa-sort` for showing sorting icon :

```
<td style="text-align: center;"> <?php echo __('No') ;?> <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i></td>
```

But result is the icon is not showed properly :

[image]

And there is an error in the console :

```
fontawesome-webfont.ttf:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I have read several post about this issue and they solved it by setting/adding mime type to `"woff2"`. But I don't know how to add that new mime type in cakePHP ?
I also have tried to put several fontawesome webfont, but this is not working also :

[image]
Need help. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found a solution :
I just change `font` directory to `fonts` and put `fontawesome-webfont.ttf` only as shown below :
[image]

And it's working like an angel
[image]

Comment: This is presumably exactly as it's referenced in the CSS file your code loads?

Comment: I'm not so sure Mr. Greg. I just saw the console errorr like `http://127.0.0.1:8888/cakephp-2.10.12/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0 ```. So it's `fonts` not `font`. So I switch to use `fonts` instead

Comment: That's what I mean. The CSS would be referencing `fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2`.

Comment: Yes yes Mr. @GregSchmidt